# Перенос строки при шифровке

Tags: c#

Есть приложение калькулятор, в котором все вычисления будут шифроваться, сохраняться в текстовый файл (каждое вычисление на новой строке), а при вызове окна "История" дешифруется содержимое файла, открывается окно с `textBlock'ом`, в который и помещается история вычислений.

Имеется строка, которую передаю в метод для шифровки (строка получает значение после нажатия кнопки `=`):

```
story_str = numb1.ToString() + " " + operation + " " + numb2.ToString() + " = " + res + Environment.NewLine;
```

Метод для шифровки (вызывается после нажатия кнопки `=`):

```
private void ToStory(string a)
        {            
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("E:\\calculations.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

            cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

            CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
               cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);


            byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a);
            crStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            crStream.Close();
            stream.Close();
}
```

Метод для дешифровки:

```
private void FromStory()
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("E:\\calculations.txt",
                              FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

            cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

            CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
                cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(crStream);

            string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Top_field.Text = data;

            reader.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
```

Однако в данном случае сохраняется в файле только последнее вычисление. А как сделать так, чтобы сохранялись все и с переносом на новую строку?

Comment: А при чем тут WPF? У вас не привязок, не MVVM...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ WPF проявляется не в этой части кода. В приложении он используется для компоновки, создания пользовательских элементов управление и ещё некоторых "фич"

Comment: Ну в этой части кода я вижу только `Top_field.Text = data;` - это можно и в WinForm сделать. Вывод - для нас от WPF тега толку ноль..

Comment: @EvgeniyZ принял к сведению